# How to resize lightbox popup in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, popup, lightbox, responsive

I am using Avada theme in WordPress and for videos lightbox. 
Have a look [here](https://www.styrouae.com/media-gallery-videos/#iLightbox[gallery]/0). I want to change the maximum size to a lower size because as it is too big.
At the same time i would like to keep the responsiveness.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Used this css

`.ilightbox-holder div.ilightbox-container {position: fixed;max-height: 980px;max-width: 1170px;width: 90% !important;height: 90% !important; top: 5%;left: 5%;right: 5%;margin: 0 auto;}
.ilightbox-holder .ilightbox-inner-toolbar {position: fixed;z-index: 100;top: 0;}`

Comment: Thanks navneet, where do I edit this css? Which file?

Comment: add for style.css and 'lightbox' .css

Comment: Did you mean to the add the code inside 'ilightbox.css' because i couldn't find 'lightbox.css'

So I did insert your code into 'ilightbox.css' but it did not work. I could find the code to replace inside 'ilightbox.css', but where exactly should I insert in 'style.css'?
Thanks for the help!